# Can't push jekyll project up to github

Tags: git, github

I had previously named the project folder `website` before renaming it "*portfolio*" I have created a new repository called `portfolio` on github but now when I try to push it up I get the following input and output

```
C:\Users\nezih\Desktop\portfolio (master) λ git add -A

C:\Users\nezih\Desktop\portfolio (master) λ git commit -m "commit" On
branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\nezih\Desktop\portfolio (master) λ git remote add origin
https://github.com/nezmustafa123/portfolio.git fatal: remote origin already exists.

C:\Users\nezih\Desktop\portfolio (master) λ git push -u origin master
remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository
'https://github.com/nezmustafa123/website.git/' not found

C:\Users\nezih\Desktop\portfolio (master) λ git status On branch
master nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I think the problem may be that git still thinks it's called "*website*"?

Comment: `git remote set-url` is your friend suggested by 2 seconds google-foo: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Answer (score 0):

You would need reset the url of the remote

`git remote set-url <name> <new-url>`

that would be

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/nezmustafa123/portfolio.git`

Now try to push to `origin`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused your local repo has already have a remote named `origin`. You can **set the `origin` with new URL** (you github repo) as the way Libin said. Or you can **add a remote** and push your local `master` to the github repo, commands as below:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/nezmustafa123/website.git
git push -u upstream master
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers I managed to get it working by creating a new folder and copying all the files into that.